# using seek() in Arduino to go to the end of a variable-sized file

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

Anyone know how to use the [seek() function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileSeek) of Arduino [SD Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) to position pointer at the end of a file?

If programming in Windows do something like:

```
void fileInsert(char *file, void *data, size_t len) {

    FILE *filePtr;

    if ((filePtr = fopen(file, "rb+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo %s não pode ser aberto.", file);
        exit(EPERM);

    } else {

        fseek(filePtr, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fwrite(data, len, 1, filePtr);
        fclose(filePtr);
    }
}
```

But the Arduino does not have the SEEK_END

Answer (score 3):

You can only seek to an absolute position from the start of the file.  Fortunately there is the `size()` method that can tell you where the end is, though.

```
file.seek(file.size());
```